# How can I create a hyperlink via the command line?

Tags: html, hyperlink, echo, command-line-arguments, cat

I would like to generate a directory of links for some friends who are not technologically savvy. I'm running Ubuntu and would like to do this via the command line.

My attempts so far have been:

`touch https:...`

which returns:

`touch: cannot touch 'https:...': No such file or directory`

`cat >> https://...`

which also returns the `No such file or directory` exception.

I also tried `echo` where the link was the filename and the file type was `.html`, which returned the same exception.

If I drag and drop the link from the address bar into a folder, it creates the hyperlink - however I would like to batch these according to a list of links.

EDIT: This can be done in Python.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/112267/create-clickable-links-in-terminal

Comment: Thanks, that led me to refine my question in a way which led me to a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63549586/how-can-i-create-a-hyperlink-via-the-command-line/63550031#63550031) on SO which supplied an alternative using Python.

Answer (score -2):

you could try the following

```
$ ln -s {source-filename} {symbolic-filename}
```

- source-filename - the target file which you want to create the link
  for
- symbolic-filename - the name of the symbolic link

Example:

```
ln -s source_file.txt link_file.txt
```

You can verify the link creating using the following command

```
ls -l link_file.txt
```